# Unresponsive UIButtons in cameraOverlayView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uibutton

I have been searching through other StackOverflow questions for a while, trying to find a solution for this, to no avail. I have the following code, which attempts to add 2 buttons to a cameraOverlayView:

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;


    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [_cancelPicture addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_takePic addTarget:self action:@selector(takePic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview: _cancelPicture];
    [picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview: _takePic];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_cancelPicture];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_takePic];

    _imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return YES;
}
```

imageView is my UIImageView. cancelPicture should return the user to a previous view controller, and takePic should save a photo and then display it (again, on another view controller.) When I deploy the code, the buttons show up, but clicking on them does nothing. I know that my delegate methods are implemented correctly, therefore I don't see the need to replicate them here. I have the following IBActions as well, though I'm not sure that they do any good:

```
- (IBAction)cancelPicture:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self imagePickerControllerDidCancel:_imagePickerController];
}

- (IBAction)takePic:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_imagePickerController takePicture];
}
```

These actions connect to the appropriate view controllers in my storyboard.

**EDIT:** Delegate methods:

```
// For responding to the user tapping Cancel.
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];

}

// For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
    }
    _imageView.image = imageToSave;

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints or used `NSLog` statements to determine whether or not these methods are being called?  Where are `_cancelPicture` and `_takePic` declared?

Comment: After adding `[_cancelPicture addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and `[_takePic addTarget:self action:@selector(takePic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`, it is evident through NSLog placement within the IBActions that they are being called, but nothing is happening. I'll edit the post to include the delegate methods they call; I used them in another project and they worked fine, but they may not be working properly here.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, other than the `NSLog` statement?  Do the methods they're calling know about `_imagePickerController`?  Is it non-`nil`?  What do the methods they're calling do?

Comment: As I stated, `cancelPicture` should return the user to a previous view controller and `takePic` should save the picture to the camera roll, and then display it on a subsequent view controller. `_imagePickerController` is a non-nil `UIImagePickerController`, and yes the methods do know about it.

Comment: Neither method works?

Comment: No, neither method works.